# Windows 7: Apps start, but never appear, only take ~100K memory

Tags: windows-7

I've been experiencing a weird issue where apps (Firefox, Dropbox, SABnzbd, foobar2000, VLC, Media Player Classic etc) won't appear/aren't accessible.

Internet Explorer: After clicking on the icon in taskbar for Firefox/etc, the icon will be active (has an outline) briefly before the border disappears.  Then, nothing... It's as though I never did anything.  I check Task Manager, and see the Process is listed but the memory is ~100 K only.  Killing the process doesn't fix things for me -- the behavior keeps happening until I reboot.

I've re-installed Windows 7 Pro 64-bit; it's fully patched.  Grabbed AVG Free -- nothing turns up in a scan.  Seems to be if I start an app immediately after startup/login, things go OK but eventually I encounter this behavior with some app.

I'd Google, but I can't think/find a worthy description...

Comment: This occasionally happens to me too. I usually just kill the running process(es) and that fixes it.

Comment: Does this happen with Notepad, Paint, or Calculator? How about the command-prompt (`cmd.exe`)? When you say “tray” do you mean the taskbar?

Comment: @Synetech inc.: Correct, taskbar.  I haven't tried with the apps you mentioned, but WinExplorer has suffered the same behavior (doesn't appear, but is listed as a process in TaskManager) -- I generally reboot as soon as I encounter the behavior.  Takes two or three before things are normal again.

Comment: The apps I mentioned are tools that come with Windows. I was thinking that it could be a dependency problem, but it’s starting to sound more like a resource or corruption problem. Have you used Windows Update recently? Try running a system scan in the command-prompt: `sfc /scannow`. Also try booting into safe-mode and running a scan in there.

Comment: @Synetech inc.: Will look into tomorrow, thx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a rootkit sweeper?  I have read that some kits can survive a normal reformatting of the OS.  Microsoft just launched a sweeper application (in beta) that you can boot from disk.

http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper

Comment: That is my fear.  I haven't tried this yet -- appreciate the link!